# Transaction submitted through Infura, but not from local node

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, blockchain, infura

So, I have a Rinkeby fast sync on my server. When I try to interact with my contract and transfer something, geth says "Submitted transaction", but then I can't find it using its hash on etherscan. When I call the same contract function through Infura's Rinkeby node, with the same gas settings, etc., it does get propagated and I can see it on etherscan within a minute.

Anyone have any idea why that might happen? I noticed that when I list my peers, the network section looks like this:

```
network: {
  inbound: false,
  localAddress: "blabla:57204",
  remoteAddress: "blabla:30305",
  static: false,
  trusted: false
},
```

Should inbound be true in order for my node to submit transactions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your node fully synced? Check the last block returned by `eth.blockNumber` is close to the last mined block. Ensure your node is connected to other peers `admin.peers`.